# iOS google places api key not working

Tags: google-maps, mapkit, google-places-api, google-places

I want to implement autocomplete feature for google places.

I have created a project on google with places api service enabled.I am using iOS key for getting json data but getting following JSON response

{
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

I am also trying same request in safari with browser key, but still I am getting same response.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Though this question has been answered by the creator itself, but I would like to tell few more points in detail as many people face this issue.

If you are using Google Pods / SDK then create iOS Key / Android Key whichever you want depending on your implementation.

If you are planning to use places API for autocomplete,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&location=21.76999,-122.44696&radius=500&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

then the API Keys for iOS / Android will not work, for this case you would need to create a **Browser Key** from google console.

**NOTE:** If you want to use places API in your project don't forget to enable

[image: Google Places API Web Service]

from

[Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) as shown below:

[image: Enabled API]

After this run your project / API you will get JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

solved it..every parameter was OK but I sent sensor=false in the URL when I was using laptop.